# trimming String when specific char found on String, is it possible?

Tags: c#, string

let's say I have this String:

```
String myString = "violet are blue|roses are red|this is a terrible poet";
```

I would like to trim the String whenever it found the char '|'. So when the code is executed, myString would be:

```
myString = "roses are red|this is a terrible poet";
```

and finally

```
myString = "this is a terrible poet";
```

is it possible?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private string trimString(string s)
{
   int index = s.IndexOf("|");
   return s.Substring(index+1); //returns string from this index to the end of string
}
```

**usage**

```
String myString = "violet are blue|roses are red|this is a terrible poet";

myString = trimString(myString);
```

Comment: And when `|` is not in the string?

Comment: it trims the string to "|roses are red|this is a terrible poet"
and while "|" remains on the first letter of the string, the next "|" won't be trimmed again. not efficient

Comment: that does not need downvoting, just correcting. People are funny. Just like to downvote. Just `index+1`???? :)

Comment: Sorry, it was because I thought you were not checking for `index==-1`, but now I see, it's quite clever, converted to upvote.

Comment: Just to clear up I didn't downvote, just waiting for better answer or edit that actually works, which you have provided. So upvote and answer accepted :)

Comment: No grudges. We should state reasons for downvoting when it might not be obvious to see. Thanks for being courageous to tell you were the one. :)

Comment: I did state a reason, I said "And when | is not in the string?", but should have put "-1" in the comment. Couldn't have corrected it, didn't know what you were going for. Nice answer in the end.

Comment: one more question: now that "violet are blue|" are trimmed, can I have it as String as well in case I need it? I would hoping there are 2 functions, 1 to trim which you have posted and another 1 to receive the trimmed String

Comment: Good answer, but I don't really understand why, when searching for a char everyone use IndexOf with a string parameter. There is a perfect overload to search a single char.

Comment: @Anggrian That's possible but I think you would need a second function with `s.Substring(0, index)`. There are other ways too

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
 string [] stringparts mystring.spilt('|');
```

`stringsparts` can be used to print whatever you want from it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.Split()` Method;

```
//Single Line Solution
string newString1 = myString.Split('|').Last();


//Another way
string[] arr = myString.Split('|');   //Split the string by | into an array
string newString2 = arr[arr.Length-1]; //Get the last element of the splited array



Console.WriteLine(newString1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Substring` method for this, perhaps you may want to use it as extension method. Code including trimming to first (left) and trimming to last (right) `|`:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TrimToFirst(this string s)
    {
        int index = s.IndexOf('|');
        if(index >= 0)
        {
            s = s.Substring(index + 1);
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static string TrimToLast(this string s)
    {
        int index = s.LastIndexOf('|');
        if(index >= 0)
        {
            s = s.Substring(index + 1);
        }
        return s;
    }
}

// usage
string myString = "violet are blue|roses are red|this is a terrible poet";
Console.WriteLine(myString.TrimToLast());
// outpus: this is a terrible poet
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "violet are blue|roses are red|this is a terrible poet";
var elements = myString.Split(new char[] { '|' }).Skip(1);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    sb.Append(element);
    sb.Append("|");
}

string result = sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).ToString();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the 100,000000 ways to do this

```
string myString = "violet are blue|roses are red|this is a terrible poet";
string result = myString.Contains('|') ? myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf('|')).TrimStart('|') : myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

A short way of implementing it:-

```
myString = myString.Substring(myString.LastIndexOf("|") + 1);
```