# C# - how can I delete a specific part of a String?

Tags: c#, string

as a continuation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891062/c-sharp-trimming-string-when-specific-char-found-on-string-is-it-possible/13891121#comment19137656_13891121) question

Let's say I have a String:

```
String myString = "violet are blue|roses are red|this is a terrible poet";
```

and I want to trim the specific part where it say "roses are red|" so that it become:

```
myString = "violet are blue|this is a terrible poet";
```

Comment: If you look at the answers of your previous question, I think you will find many ways to do this. Don't be so lazy....

Comment: You could do a string `Split` operation on `"|"`, and then join.

Comment: @Matthew join which parts?

Comment: @möter The parts that are not part you want to omit.

Comment: @Matthew of course, but that sounds too involved to me.

Comment: You should ask the entire question here, otherwise the `String.Replace("roses are red|","")` answers will be the ones you get, seeing how you ask exactly that.

Comment: just to be clear, I learnt Substring in my first question, which can only delete first part or last part of the String. But now I'm talking what if the part I want to delete is on the middle of the original String?

Comment: @Anggrian String.Substring can't be used to 'delete'. It returns another string, that is identical to a subset of the original string.

Comment: @möter yes but my point isn't the word "delete" "remove" "replace" "manipulate" or any other words you prefer. But the idea that Substring method may only 'delete' String from index to index.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method

```
string input = "violet are blue|roses are red|this is a terrible poet";
string expected = "violet are blue|this is a terrible poet";
string actual = input.Replace("roses are red|", String.Empty);        

Debug.Assert(expected == actual);
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? It does the job, doesn't it?

Comment: This answers the question exactly, but if you look at that previous question you can see that he actually want's to remove the last section that ends with `|`.

Comment: +1 simple and gets the job done

Comment: no it doesn't really related with my previous question, I would hoping to delete the specific part in the string. While I learnt String.Substring in my first question, which could only delete first part or last part of the string

Comment: @oleksii I agree, it's not my downvote, I upped actually ;)

Comment: This only works if the part to remove never can exist anywhere else in the string. For example using it to remove the middle part of `"pineapple|apple|orange"` gives `"pineorange"` instead of `"pineapple|orange"`.

Comment: @Guffa I am not sure I am following. I am just answering the question without any additional assumptions. The question was: *how can I delete a specific part of a String?*. *String.Replace()* does the job. If needed, he can use regexp for more advanced replacement and search.

Comment: @oleksii: Using `Replace` to remove part of a string is a very limited way to do it. It only works if what you remove never can exist anywhere else in the string. It works for the given example in the question, but it can very easily break when the input isn't already known.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that it's the `|` characters that you want to use to find what to remove.

Get the index of the first `|` using `IndexOf`, then the second, then get the remaining parts of the string using `Remove`:

```
int index1 = myString.IndexOf('|');
int index2 = myString.IndexOf('|', index1 + 1);
myString = myString.Remove(index1, index2 - index1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using split:

```
const string myString = "violet are blue|roses are red|this is a terrible poet";
const char itemToSplitOn = '|';

var arr = myString.Split(itemToSplitOn);
var newString = arr[0] + itemToSplitOn + arr[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

The question wouldn't be a complete one without a regex answer :)

```
String myString = "violet are blue|roses are red|this is a terrible poet";
var newstr = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\|.+?\|", "|");
```